# Multiple If - else in php

Tags: php

My PHP code looks like that.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
if(isset($_GET['subid'])) {
    $subid = $_GET['subid'];
}
```

I want to get variable if `isset` and set to `0` if `!isset`. something like that

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else $id='0';
```

But as you see i have multiple if's. How can i do it? I need to write else for every if?

**UPDATE**
Ok. thx for your help. I did it. But is there any way to shorten this piece of code again?

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
$subid = isset($_GET['subid']) ? $_GET['subid'] : 0;
$feat = isset($_GET['feat']) ? $_GET['feat'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
```

Comment: @Tural, I then suggest looking at the foreach solution that Arjan has already given.

Answer (score 3):

```
$id = $subid=0;

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
}
if(isset($_GET['subid']))
{
$subid = $_GET['subid'];
}
```

you can initiate all variables at 0 before you run that code

Comment: If you're going about it that way, might as well do: `$id = $subid = 0`

Comment: Can't think of anyway to make it significantly shorter

Answer (score 2):

use a helper function:

```
function getQSValueOrDefault($name, $default){
   if (!isset($_GET[$name]))
      return $default;
   else
      return $_GET[$name];
}
```

and use it like:

```
$id = getQSValueOrDefault('id', 0); 
$subid = getQSValueOrDefault('subid', 0);
```

Comment: This could be simplified slightly using the ?: syntax

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way to get an input variable is the following:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
```

(you don't have to check if the value is set)

Other method:

```
// set default values if they are not set
// so that you don't have to check if they are set
$inputs = $_GET + array(
    'id' => 0,
    'subid' => 0,
);

$id = $inputs['id'];
$subid = $inputs['subid'];
```

Or using ternary operator:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
$subid = isset($_GET['subid']) ? $_GET['subid'] : 0;
```

Comment: The first and second methods I proposed are both shorted than the code you want to shorten.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "0";
$subid = isset($_GET['subid']) ? $_GET['subid'] : "0";
```

Comment: you have already marked this question as answered, which it is. If you really require it to be even shorter than it already is (which will just become a mess) then you should open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value){
  if ($key === 'id' || $key === 'subid'){
    if(isset($value)) {
      $$key = $value;
    }else{
      $$key = '0';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a great way to introduce unwanted variables and should be avoided as it is a potential security risk. You could make it more secure by checking the value of `$key` to a list of expected variables.

Comment: I don't think so, I would like you to have a second look; I finished it now ... and by the way: 'extract' is definte much worse ...

Comment: True, you were updating your post while I was typing my comment. This seems safe, although I would probably use `in_array()` to check `$key`.

Comment: It really depends on the number of fields. If there are more fields, I would also prefer 'in_array()'.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want several lines like:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
$subid = isset($_GET['subid']) ? $_GET['subid'] : 0;
$feat = isset($_GET['feat']) ? $_GET['feat'] : 0;
```

Then this could be an alternative.

```
$keys = array('id', 'page', 'subid', 'feat');
foreach($keys as $key)
{
    $$key = isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : 0;
}
```

Note that you loose the option to set different default values for the keys, or to treat different keys differently.

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare your `$id` and `$subid` as 0 by default. And then write a simple `if ( ... ) { }`. Like this:

```
$id = 0;
$subid = 0;

if (isset($_GET['id']))
    $id = $_GET['id'];
if (isset($_GET['subid']))
    $subid = $_GET['subid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using [extract()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)??

```
extract($_GET); // it will create all the vairables
// to set default values
$id = isset($id) ? $id : 0;
$subid = isset($subid) ? $subid : 0;
```

**EDITED:**
a more elegant way

```
$id = $subid = 0;  // set default values
extract($_GET); // it will create all the variables and overwrite default values
```

Comment: You'll just introduce unchecked user input in your code. That's potentially dangerous and should be avoided. `extract()` can be useful, but not on user input.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the ?: operators to remove the extra keyworks to make it a single line for each

```
$id= isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
$subid=isset($_GET['subid']) ? $_GET['subid'] : 0;
```

You could also create a function to do the work for you.

```
function getOrDefault($name, $default) {
  return isset($_GET[$name]) ? $_GET[$name] : $default);
}
```

This would allow you to create extra wrapper functions with defaults for various types.

```
function getInt($name) {
  return getOrDefault($name,0);
}

function getString($name) {
  return getOrDefault($name,"");
}
```

then your code becomes

```
$id = getInt('id');
$subid = get('subid');
```